# How to connect Database in AWS Lightsail?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have PHP project now.

I want to Database Connection in my PHP file I'm using AWS Lightsail, I have created separate database, but don't know how `yp` connect.

[image]

Connection in PHP File, I'm Intermediate in `Lightsail`.